# Reconnecting to Drobo over iSCSI after server reboot

Tags: server, mount

I have an iSCSI attached Drobo hooked up to a server that I use to put backups on. I connect to the Drobo using a command like:

> sudo iscsiadm -m node --login

then I find what device is new in `/dev` ussually sda1 and mount it using:

> mount /dev/sda1 /drobo

I would like to automate this everytime the system reboots. Although the Drobo ussually shows up as sda1 this is not always the case. Is there a way I can absolutely determine what device is the Drobo after running the iscsi login command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mountinf /dev/sda1, you can use `sudo blkid /dev/sda1` to determine the UUID of the partition and then modify `/etc/fstab` by replacing (or adding) the line:
`/dev/sda1 /drobo ext4 defaults,noauto 0 0`
with
`UUID=[blikd_result] /drobo ext4 defaults,noauto 0 0`
Thus it will follow the current naming of the iscsi session.